# PayPal IPN SSL protocol version

Tags: ssl, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using IPN verification code from https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php

And the problem is that I get "cURL error: [35] Unsupported SSL protocol version" on live server. Everything is working fine with sandbox account on the stage server. Now the live server has even newer Curl version which is 7.42.1. What should I do?

Here is the var_dump(curl_version()); of both of the versions:

prntscr.com/e61mff - not working

prntscr.com/e61n42 - working

Comment: The curl version itself is not sufficient because it also depends on the library used for SSL and the version of the library. Please add the output of `curl -V` from both the working and the non-working system to your question.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/e61mff - not working.
http://prntscr.com/e61n42 - working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information included in the comment it can be seen that the non-working version of curl is using OpenSSL 0.9.8zf as the underlying SSL library. This version does not include support for TLS 1.2 which is required by Paypal. You would need at least OpenSSL 1.0.1 for TLS 1.2 support.

Comment: Thank you, yes, the SSL is older on the live version. :)